# What is the best way to encourage certain types of questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

[WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) is becoming more and more popular, and [Three.js](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/) is making its name as the library for WebGL newbs.

I often find that questions in this area go unanswered for quite some time, which discourages me from asking in the first place. I've answered my own WebGL questions a majority of the time, and have gotten the Tumbleweed badge too many times for questions in these categories.

I do my best to vote up questions in these areas, and ensure the tags are present if the question involves WebGL; but is there anything else that I can do to help promote this new technology to get some love on SO?

Comment: SO is not for place for promoting any product or technology but a community for professional and enthusiast programmers. And yes if it's popular then there are more programmers developing around it so i must say they have questions/answers and confusions/conclusion at some points.

Comment: @Bhuro I think you misunderstand my intentions, I'm just using WebGL as a specific example. I'm asking in general, what can I do to help grow the community of a particular tag or area so that the questions that are lingering unanswered can get some help.

Comment: Is it that the experts in the field are preferring to use another Q/A site or forum for answering questions, or that the technology is so new that there *are* no (or very few) experts in the field?  If it's the latter, there isn't much to do other than wait.

Comment: @Bhuro It doesn't seem to me that the OP is asking to promote the product. Simply asking how to help what he perceives to be ignored questions get answered.

Comment: Use your own social network to bring in more interest. Twitter, Google+, facebook, your blog, subject-specific mailing lists. Make sure the experts *know the questions exist*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ... so now we need to get *friends*?! where do you get those from??

Comment: @Mike: I bought them from a SEO expert to follow my Twitter account! They are really pretty too!

Comment: @MartijnPieters *Make sure the experts know the questions exist* you mean like including a link to the SO tag page from [the technology's website](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o831o.png)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: Yup, if the project itself links, then that helps tremendously, of course. The [Plone project](http://plone.org/support) does this too, to [my benefit](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/plone/topusers).

Comment: [webgl] currently has a 23% unanswered question rate, which puts it ahead of [android] at 30% and [ios] at 26%. Even a related technology, [opengl-es], has a 26% unanswered rate, and I know a number of 3-D experts hang out there. That doesn't look so bad to me.